Does anyone know of a look-up table or mapping from language code to the CSS style "list-style-type"?
The CSS property list-style-type lets you pick the style of the letter or number that goes in front of a list item, like "A,B,C" or "ii,iii,iv". Some list-style-types are "decimal", "lower-roman", "hebrew", "bengali", "thai", "urdu", "trad-chinese-informal".
I would love to see a look-up table or mapping or something that converts from language code (ISO 639) to list-style-type, so I can place the correct list-style-type for the right language.
Does anybody know of anything like this?

I'm not clear that such a list could exist - at least not as a definitive one given e.g. that some languages may be associated with several (informal and formal for example). I suspect you'd be safer deciding on each one yourself when setting the language code.

Are you asking for a finished list, or how to do it yourself? If it's the latter, then you can use the :lang() selector, for example:
:lang(he) ol, ol:lang(he) {
    list-style-type: hebrew;
}

Where the lang attribute set on a surrounding element, or the element itself.

I'm looking for a finished list. I have the current language, which would be "he" in this case. Then I would like to look up and receive back the style type "hebrew". What if the language was "ar" or "ur"? What style should I use for those? I don't know. This is the list I'm looking for.
